# How to fetch limited record for same value

Tags: mysql

I have a table `media`, in which I have the fields `id`, `image_path` and `uploaded_date`.

My media table data.

```
id | image_path             | uploaded_date 
---+------------------------+--------------
324   /media/job/plumber.jpeg  2015-04-20
323   /media/job/plumbe1.jpeg  2015-04-20
322   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-20
321   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-20
320   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-17
319   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-17
318  /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-14
317   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-09
316   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-09
315   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-03
314   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-03
313   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-03
312  /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg   2015-04-03
310   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-02
309   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-02
308   /media/job/plumbe2.jpeg  2015-04-02
```

and so on...

I use the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.`uploaded_date`) FROM media u2
WHERE 
u2.`uploaded_date` > u1.`uploaded_date`) + 1 AS week, `uploaded_date`,`id` FROM media u1
ordeR BY week
```

I get result like following.

```
week | uploaded_date | id
-----+---------------+----
1   2015-04-20        324   
1   2015-04-20        323   
1   2015-04-20        322   
1   2015-04-20        321   
2   2015-04-17        319   
2   2015-04-17        320   
3   2015-04-14        318   
4   2015-04-09        316   
4   2015-04-09        317   
5   2015-04-03        312   
5   2015-04-03        314   
5   2015-04-03        315   
5   2015-04-03        313   
6   2015-04-02        308   
6   2015-04-02        309   
6   2015-04-02        310   
6   2015-04-02        311
```

Now what I want is I only want to fetch the first two records of the week.

Desired output is folowing:

```
    week | uploaded_date | id
    -----+---------------+----
    1   2015-04-20        324   
    1   2015-04-20        323   
    2   2015-04-17        319   
    2   2015-04-17        320   
    3   2015-04-14        318   
    4   2015-04-09        316   
    4   2015-04-09        317   
    5   2015-04-03        312   
    5   2015-04-03        314   
    6   2015-04-02        308   
    6   2015-04-02        309
```

Can anyone help me? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think your expected values are wrong, for week 5 you should get id 315 and 314. Also, for week 6 you should have 310 and 311, right?

Comment: @McAdam331, yes you are right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a really good [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) about getting the greatest-n-per-group, which is what you're trying to do here. There's also a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) for it on the site.

When I do this, my most common approach is the use a correlated subquery by adding a subquery in the where clause that orders items, and ensures their count is less than or equal to what you want.

In this case, we want to order items by `id` in a descending, group by `week`, and ensure the number of items returned is less than 2, so we can do so like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable mT
  WHERE m.week = mT.week AND m.upload_date = mT.upload_date AND m.id <= mT.id) <= 2;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f936/2) example. Note, this is assuming the two rows you want are the two largest `id`s for each week, because that's what most of your expected results suggest. If that is not what you want, please let me know and I can edit accordingly.

**EDIT**

Since 'week' is not actually part of your table, just remove it from my query above, it will still work:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable mT
  WHERE m.upload_date = mT.upload_date AND m.id <= mT.id) <= 2;
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41c61/1) link.

Comment: Should that be `< 2`?

Comment: @Arth no, because that will only return 1 row per group. Try it in the Fiddle to see.

Comment: You may get better performance with two `<` s as there are less rows to count.

Comment: @Arth that's a good suggestion, and both options return the same results. However, using `EXPLAIN` seems to show the same procedure for each: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f936/10

Comment: @McAdam331, your answer is right but you can see my query. week is not table field. i take sub query answer into variable named "week". and i want only top two records of each week. like from week one,2 records. from week two another top 2 records.

Comment: @Jazz One thing you can do is just replace 'myTable' with your query and it should work the same. If you post some raw data from your table, and not the query results I can try to make it work for you.

Comment: @McAdam331, now you can see my edited question. u will get rough idea about my table and my desired output.

Comment: @McAdam331, Thanks a lot for your kind response. Your answer helps me for my desired output. i slightly modified your query and get my output. see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same result using a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
   SELECT m.week, m.upload_date, m.id
     FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN myTable mj
       ON mj.week = m.week
      AND mj.upload_date = m.upload_date
      AND mj.id > m.id
 GROUP BY m.week, m.upload_date, m.id
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
 ORDER BY week, id DESC
```

**N.B.** I this will only work as is for 2 or more rows from each group

Answer (score 0):

Here i get my desired output.

i use following query.

```
SELECT WEEK( m.uploaded_date ) , DATE_ADD( m.uploaded_date, INTERVAL( 1 - DAYOFWEEK( m.uploaded_date ) ) 
DAY ) as start_date, DATE_ADD( m.uploaded_date, INTERVAL( 7 - DAYOFWEEK( m.uploaded_date ) ) 
DAY ) as end_date, m.uploaded_date, m.image_path
FROM media m
WHERE (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM media mT
WHERE WEEK( m.uploaded_date ) = WEEK( mT.uploaded_date ) 
AND m.id <= mT.id
) <=2
ORDER BY WEEK( m.uploaded_date )
```

And my output:

```
week | start_date  | end_date | uploaded_date 
7      2015-02-15   2015-02-21  2015-02-19  
7      2015-02-15   2015-02-21  2015-02-19  
8      2015-02-22   2015-02-28  2015-02-26  
8      2015-02-22   2015-02-28  2015-02-26  
9      2015-03-01   2015-03-07  2015-03-04  
9      2015-03-01   2015-03-07  2015-03-04
10     2015-03-08   2015-03-14  2015-03-12  
10     2015-03-08   2015-03-14  2015-03-12  
11     2015-03-15   2015-03-21  2015-03-20  
11     2015-03-15   2015-03-21  2015-03-20
```

As you can see i get start date and end date from uploaded_date. From start date and end date of week i get only two records for each week.In short i get two records from each week. if there is more than two records in week, still this will give me two records.

Thanks.
Hope this will help others.